# How to fix this code? Passing String from method to MainActivity

Tags: java, android, json

I can't pass the jsonParse method variables. I tried to save them in the "ArrayList " but the Array remains empty. With another method, ex. "test", it works.
Why?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gridView = findViewById(R.id.griglia);
    mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    txt = findViewById(R.id.titolo);
    movieList= new ArrayList<Movie>();
```

//
I call the metod jsonParse for to fill my ArrayList

```
    jsonParse();
    if(movieList.isEmpty()){
        txt.setText("vuoto");
    }
    else{
        txt.setText("pieno");
    }

}
```

// I have a problem with this code. He works, but don't fill the ArrayList

```
public void jsonParse(){
    String url ="https://api.myjson.com/bins/tn67c";
    JsonObjectRequest request= new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray= response.getJSONArray("movie");

                        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject emplyee = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String titolo = emplyee.getString("titolo");
                            String url = emplyee.getString("url");
                            String icona= emplyee.getString("icona");


                            Movie movie= new Movie();
                            movie.setTitolo(titolo);
                            movie.setVideoFilePath(url);
                            movieList.add(i, movie);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    mQueue.add(request);

}
```

//
I trust with a example method "prova" and now work it. Why?

```
public void prova(){
    int i=0;

    for(i=0; i<2; i++){
        String test= "ciao " + i;
        Movie movie= new Movie();
        movie.setTitolo(test);
        movieList.add(movie);
    }

}
```

Comment: are you sur you are getting your json ?

Comment: Yes, it works with: text.setText(titolo) in jsonparse into for(i=0...)

Comment: could you do a break point to on movieList.add(i, movie); to see what is the value of titulo

Comment: I thought so too. But it doesn't fill.

Comment: so check why , you start find where is the probleme

Comment: The ArrayList fill in jsonParse. But after, when it return to OnCreate, the ArrayList is empty

Comment: check my answer

Comment: @Giorgio, you are saying that the ArrayList fill in jsonParse method, but when it returns to onCreate, the ArrayList is empty; that could be because after jsonParse() method, you are initializing a new instance of the ArrayList in onCreate, so your ArrayList will be empty

Comment: @HyunJin  I tryed to initializing ArrayList before to OnCreate, but it doesn't work.


   ArrayList<Movie> movieList= new ArrayList<Movie>();

Comment: Is your jsonParse() method inside the MainActivity?

Comment: This is very confusing question. Are you asking about parsing? Or about sending data to MainActivity? You write a lot but don't tell us the exact problem. Help us to help you, or this question will get downvotes instead of answers.

Comment: @HyunJin Yes, it is inside on method OnCreate

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier when i try to save the strings in movieList, after the loop MovieList returns empty.
In the loop it fills up, but in the OnCreate it remains empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are initialing `movieList` after calling request please call before , try to initialize your list before `onCreate`

```
  ArrayList<Movie>  movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
```

And put this

```
if(movieList.isEmpty()){ 
  txt.setText("vuoto"); 
 } else{ 
  txt.setText("pieno"); 
  }
```

right after you finish adding item in the list

**Edit:**

```
package com.example.zvideo2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    String url ="https://api.myjson.com/bins/tn67c";
    private RequestQueue mQueue;
    ArrayList<Movie> movieList= new ArrayList<Movie>();
    TextView txt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        txt = findViewById(R.id.titolo);

        jsonParse();
//        prova();

    }


    public void jsonParse(){

        String url ="https://api.myjson.com/bins/tn67c";

        JsonObjectRequest request= new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray= response.getJSONArray("movie");

                            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                                JSONObject emplyee = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String titolo = emplyee.getString("titolo");
                                String url = emplyee.getString("url");
                                String icona= emplyee.getString("icona");

                                Movie movie= new Movie();
                                movie.setTitolo(titolo);
                                movie.setVideoFilePath(url);
                                movieList.add(i, movie);
                            }

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "item add successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            if(movieList.isEmpty()){
                            txt.setText("vuoto");
                            }else{
                            txt.setText("pieno");
                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        mQueue.add(request);
        mQueue.start(request);

    }

    public void prova(){
        int i=0;

        for(i=0; i<2; i++){
            String test= "ciao " + i;
            Movie movie= new Movie();
            movie.setTitolo(test);
            movieList.add(movie);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I tried your answer, but unfortunately it doesn't work. App crash and movieList is empty

Comment: I tryed but doesn't work... 

Edit Code:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RequestQueue mQueue;
    ArrayList<Movie> movieList= new ArrayList<Movie>();
    TextView txt;

Comment: Please just check that you are getting the json right and your code reach the point where you add item in the movie list

Comment: And set your text after you add item in your list after the loop directly

Comment: Yes, it work and i see my json code. If i set text into loop it works, but I want the data to remain saved in the listMovie

Comment: It will remains dont worry

Comment: I add this for testing and work:
txt.append(movie.getTitolo());
But i need mediaList full later the loop

Comment: Unfortunaty no. It is empty after the loop

Comment: Are you sure you are not emptying the list somewhere in your code or initializing it ?

Comment: Yes i'm sure because if i try to use prova() instead to jsonparse() all work perfectly.

Comment: Could you please post all the code together to see what is happening? I will check it

Comment: Yes, sure. I use this site for share my code for you. https://pastebin.com/G1NHFDNv

Comment: please use the code i put on my edit , it should work and also let me know if the toast is shown

Comment: It works. But if i create txt2.setText(movieList.get(1).getTitolo()); in method OnCreate,  movieList doesn't work. But if i create a Button and i insert txt2.setText(movieList.get(1).getTitolo()); in setOnClickListner it work. Why? I would like to work without button for read my elements in movieList

Comment: please consider my answer as correct if it resolved the problem in the question , and for the second problem because in your oncreate you Movielist is still empty , but in your clicklistener i think the movielist get element so you can set the text .

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `jsonParse` uses callback `onResponse(JSONObject response)`, so it is executed on background thread.

Try to debug it, set breakpoint in your `onResponse` method and there you set your list to TextView.

I think it will stop firstly there you set text to TextView and then in `onResponse` method